# Как убрать gzip Компрессию при получении ответа с GET запроса?

Tags: requests, vba, header, gzip

Делаю запрос на api через VBA Excel, чтобы записать данные, но долго не понимал, почему выходит странный ответ
[image: Вот пример]

Потом после поиска на разных форумах понял, что это gzip компрессия, так как в header`e увидел этот заголовок.
Вот мой исходник

```
Dim strResult2 As String
Dim objHTTP2 As Object
Dim URL2 As String
Set objHTTP2 = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL2 = "https://site.com/api"
objHTTP2.Open "GET", URL2, False
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip , deflate, br"
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.37"
objHTTP2.send

response = objHTTP2.responseText

Debug.Print response
```

Как я понял всё сделано в setHeaders, но пока не нашёл правильный ответ, который выдавал мне нормальный json без gzip

```
{ "name": "Test" }
```

Пробовал уже > `"Accept-Encoding", "identity, deflate"`  , `"Accept-Encoding", "identity,gzip;q=0"`

Ничего не помогает ;C

Comment: Ну вы же сами шлете серверу `Accept-Encoding` чем говорите ему, что клиент умеет в сжатие и потому можно сжимать.

Comment: А по стандарту, даже в обычных тестах API при запросе там стоит этот заголовок. Я решил может VBA его не видит и надо разрешить его. Оказалось нет. К слову (Заголов Accept-Encoding убрал, а  кракозябры GZIP так-же на месте)

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?613302-RESOLVED-Decompress-GZip

Answer (score 0):

Поискал по англоязычным форумам, везде говорят, что нужно явно указать, что сжатие не поддерживается:

```
objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "identity"
```

Правда сервер имеет право обидеться и ответить `406 Not Acceptable`

Comment: Попытался, не получилось, такие-же кракозябры ;'C

Comment: Может есть аналоги WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"?
Просто когда делаю запрос на PowerShell , у меня все данные в нормальном формате.
А вот с XMLHTTP60 у меня проблемы по части входа, он не подходит)